# Does * mean transpose in some scientific reports?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, kalman-filter

I'm reading this [report](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.1421&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about Square Root Kalman Filter and I'm stuck at the line

$$S_k^- = qr\left \{\left [ \sqrt{W_1^{(c)}} \left ( \chi^*_{1:2L,k|k-1} - \hat x_k^- \right ) \sqrt{R_v}     \right ] \right \}$$

Where $W_i^{(c)} \in \Re^N$, $\chi^* \in \Re^{L x N}$, $\hat x_k^- \in \Re^{L}$ and $N = 2L + 1$ and $L > 0 \in \Re$

**Questions:**

1. If $[Q,R] = qr(A)$ where $A \in \Re^{L x N}$, $Q \in \Re^{N x N}$ and $R \in \Re^{N x L}$. That means that $A = \left [ \sqrt{W_1^{(c)}} \left ( \chi^*_{1:2L,k|k-1} - \hat x_k^- \right ) \sqrt{R_v}     \right ]$. What size has $R_v$ ?
2. Should I multiply or concatenate $\sqrt{R_v}$ with $\sqrt{W_1^{(c)}} \left ( \chi^*_{1:2L,k|k-1} - \hat x_k^- \right )$ ?
3. Is $\chi^*$ the transpose or just a matrix?
4. Is $R_v$ diagonal?

I'm writing this to pure C code in [CControl](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl) library at the GitHub.

Comment: $*$ gets used to denote many different things in mathematics. In linear algebra, it usually denotes the conjugate transpose, where you both tranpose the matrix, and take the complex conjugate of all of its elements. If you are dealing with real matrices only, then it is just the transpose.